# How to bulk upload data through excel file into the mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm using the following code but it's showing parse error so anyone please provide me the appropriate solution?

```
/****** Include the EXCEL Reader Factory ***********/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'excel.php';

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_FILES['excelupload']['name'])) {
    //print_r($_FILES['excelupload']);
    $namearr = explode(".",$_FILES['excelupload']['name']);

    if(end($namearr) != 'xls' && end($namearr) != 'xlsx') {
        echo '<p> Invalid File </p>';
        $invalid = 1;
    }

    if($invalid != 1) {
        $response = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excelupload']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['excelupload']['name']); // Upload the file to the current folder

        if($response) {
            try {
                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['excelupload']['name']);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die('Error : Unable to load the file : "'.pathinfo($_FILES['excelupload']['name'],PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
            }

            $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
            $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Total Number of rows in the uploaded EXCEL file
            $string = "insert into ".tablename." (name,city,designation) VALUES('".$name."','".$city."','".$designation."')";

            for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++) {
                $name = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
                $city = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
                $designation = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
                $string .= "('".$name."','".$city."','".$designation."')";
            }

            $string = substr($string,0,-1);
            mysql_query($string);          // Insert all the data into one query
        }
    }// End Invalid Condition
}
```

Comment: So perhaps tell us the exact error message that you're getting rather than make us wade through your code to see what syntax errors you might have

Answer (score 0):

One big roblem is that you're creating a MySQL statement as a string

```
$string = "insert into ".tablename." (name,city,designation) VALUES('".$name."','".$city."','".$designation."')";
```

using the variables `$name`, `$city` and `$designation` before they're defined..... then extending that string inside your loop.

That creates a string something like:

```
insert into myTable (name,city,designation) VALUES ('','','')('A','B','C')('D','E','F')
```

which isn't valid SQL

Switch to using MySQLi or PDO with a prepared statement and placeholders, then binding the variables to the placeholders and executing the query in your loop.

Prepared statement and placeholders aren't available with the old deprecated MySQL interface (which you shouldn't be using these days anyway because it is old and deprecated).

I'd suggest switching to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and reading up on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

**EDIT**

Here's the basis of code to do it using MySQLi.... you'll have to create your own database connection and any error handling yourself

```
$query = "insert into " . tablename . " (name,city,designation) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
for ($i = 2; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {
    $name        = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
    $city        = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
    $designation = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $name, $city, $designation);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Read the PHP documentation and learn how this works

Comment: You please provide me the correct code by which i could import the data into the mysql database

Comment: Start by reading the linked documents on using prepared statements and then have a go at writing it yourself.... I've told you what you're doing wrong; I've told you how you should re-write it to fix it

Comment: still m not able to rectified it so you please provide me the exact solution